# Enforcing instance variable implementation from an abstract class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I am trying to design an abstract class which will enforce implementation of an instance variable even though the type if this instance variable is unknown at the abstract level. For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractDiet{
    abstract void computeMeat()
    abstract void computeVeggies()
    …
}

public abstract class AbstractAnimal{
    protected AbstractDiet diet;
    …   
}
```

Then I'd like users to implement something like:

```
public class Cat extends AbstractAnimal{
    protected CatFoodDiet diet;   // CatFoodDiet extends AbstractDiet
    …
}
```

Is this the best way to implement the `diet` variable? I want to ENFORCE that a subclass of AbstractDiet is always implemented in a subclass of AbstractAnimal.

Comment: `I want to ENFORCE that a subclass of AbstractDiet is always implemented in a subclass of AbstractAnimal.`  This statement doesn't make sense. You don't implement a variable or field. You initialize it. What are you really asking?

Comment: I want to ensure that a subclass of AbstractDiet is present in any subclass AbstractAnimal. Since AbstractDiet is itself an abstract class, I want to design a way so the user always knows to declare a concrete subclass of AbstractDiet. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think he's asking about the differences between [abstract classes and interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Comment: How can I declare this variable in the interface? It's an abstract class and cannot be initialized.

Comment: Don't declare public variables (see my answer, below).  Declare getters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:  Keep your instance variables private, and provide accessor methods.

Second of all:  It sounds like you are trying to define an interface.  Use an interface any time you want to say something like, "every animal has a diet."

```
interface Animal {
    Diet getDiet();
    ...
 }
```

If you like, you can also incorporate Bohemian's idea, and make it generic.

```
interface Animal<D extends Diet> {
    D getDiet();
    ...
}
```

That way, you will have maximum freedom when it comes time to define different kinds of animal

```
class Cat implements Animal<CatDiet> {
    CatDiet getDiet() { return...; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the solution I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (and shouldn't) approach the design like that. Using abstract classes, try something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDiet {
    abstract void compute();
}
public abstract class AbstractAnimal<T extends AbstractDiet> { 
    protected T diet;
}
public class CatFoodDiet extends AbstractDiet {
    compute() {
        //
    }
}
public class Cat extends AbstractAnimal<CatFoodDiet> {
    // use field in super which is type CatFoodDiet
}
```

But typically you would use interfaces instead of abstract classes for the abstract types.

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way is to just require the subclass to provide the information:

```
public abstract class AbstractAnimal {
    // Subclasses must provide a function that returns the diet
    public abstract AbstractDiet getDiet();
}

public class PetRock extends AbstractAnimal {
    @Override
    public AbstractDiet getDiet() {
        return new SunlightDiet();
    }
}
```

If you want to force a particular implementation, this is a common way:

```
public abstract class AbstractAnimal {
    private AbstractDiet diet;

    // Provide a constructor that sets a diet
    protected AbstractAnimal(AbstractDiet aDiet) {
        if (null == aDiet)
            throw new NullPointerException("Diet must be specified");
        diet = aDiet;
}

public class PetRock extends AbstractAnimal {
    public PetRock() {
        // Subclasses have to provide a diet to the superclass
        super(new SunlightDiet());
    }
}
```